Cómo funciona HPL de informix, específicamente onploadm?
Hola veran he está usando la onpladm de informix para exportar una gran carga de registros de una tabla de la manera más rápida posible, ya que hasta ahora para hacer una migración la forma más rápida a sido exportando un csv con los datos de informix y después cargandolos en postgres con pgbulkload, pero hasta el momento no he entendido del todo como funciona Hpl, solo lo he usado definiendo primero un onpladm create project ProyectoTest, después un onpladm create job TablaJobTest -p ProyectoTest -D Base_de_datos -t tabla -d "/ruta/archivo.txt" -z D y por último un onpladm run job TablaJobTest -p ProyectoTest -o "/ruta/logs.log" esto exporta satisfactoriamente mi tabla a un CSV pero por más que busco no logro encontrar una configuración para cambiar el delimitador (Por defecto viene un Pipe |), Agradecería cualquier ayuda sobre como cambiar el delimitador, el uso de Hpl de informix en su versión Server 12.10 y de onpladm, o bien si conocen una manera de migrar de forma eficiente de esa versión de informix a postgres 15.3 también es bienvenida la ayuda.

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
